# Autocompletion not working in virtual environment pycharm

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, virtualenv, pycharm

I am currently working on a `Django Project` and installed `djangorestframework` on my installed apps. My `pip freeze` file you can see below:

```
Django==1.9.2
django-filter==0.12.0
djangorestframework==3.3.2
djangorestframework-jwt==1.7.2
eventbrite==3.3.3
Markdown==2.6.5
Pygments==2.1
PyJWT==1.4.0
requests==2.9.1
wheel==0.24.0
```

My project `python interpreter` is also pointing to the right directory

[image]

But the issue is `auto completion` feature is not working for `djangorestframework`, as you can see below. `Pycharm` is not recognizing my imports here.

[image]

I have also enabled `Django Support` in `Pycharm`.

Could anyone suggest me what should I do to enable autocompletion here? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Okay my issue is resolved

> ```
> 1 - Go to `file --> Invalidate Caches/Restart`
> 2-  Wait for Pycharm to build new indexes 
> 3-  Then try to import your python modules.
> ```

It worked for me :)

[image]